# Why are people voting down my good posts?

Tags: discussion

I mostly post on the main site but since this is about that site itself I decided this belonged on meta. I needed hep with upgrading to VMware Worstation 11 but Workstation said I needed drivers for OpenGL 3.2. I installed drivers from Intel, I wasn't sure which version was which version, but nothing helped, even with all the research, it upgraded everything but what I wanted it to. I had this PC since 2012, why would Intel drop it? I've heard they support a 5 year old graphics card... Also, can anyone tell me what's wrong with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557154/does-ubuntu-have-support-drivers-for-my-graphics-card) post, as I clearly don't see why it's been abandoned and voted down. I'm not really popular with my questions as I have the Tumbleweed badge.

Comment: The question could be better quality by having specs linked to in something like http://paste.ubuntu.com/. The question title may not be appropriate for what you are asking, because you can start here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/. It is really hard to read, and some things are not needed (like Weight 24.03 lbs.). I didn't downvote this though. :) It may just be trying to use 3d graphics with a VM, and is not related to Windows Aero, or necessarily Ubuntu.

Comment: That is a good post? I'd hate to see one of your bad posts.

Answer (score 5):

Some people think answering questions is more difficult than asking. I think it is the other way around. Looking into the example in your post:

The worst thing you can do is to give a lot of information *before* you even created the beginning of a framework to place it in. Only people who are desperate to understand what you mean will continue to read after the first section of your question. I wouldn't.

Those who *do* continue to read, find out that at least half of the information they kept in their mind's "RAM" turns out to be irrelevant. After reading the whole question, it is still quite unclear what you're asking.

I am not much of a downvoter, I didn't, and I am sure your question is sincere. When I would run into the question in review however, I am pretty sure I would vote to close, due to "unclear what you're asking".

I suggest you ask questions in a ordered format: clear title with a clear question > clear framework of the question, making clear what information is relevant > then *only* that relevant information, without story- telling (no one needs to know you switched to NVIDIA, but then again you didn't).

Answer (score 2):

When I read [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557154/does-ubuntu-have-support-drivers-for-my-graphics-card) post, I have trouble getting at what you're really asking.  Here's what I read:

I used this one Nvidia card one time.
Read these 50 lines to find out which card it was please.
I'm throwing in this VMware error.  I won't tell you if it's because I'm trying to run Ubuntu in a VM on Windows or Windows in a VM on Ubuntu.

So, could you just know what I'm asking then answer my hardware recommendation question?

*Just a note:  if not for the VMware error message, it would have been duped to the one "What hardware does Ubuntu support" as is, it will probably get closed as unclear*

Answer (score 0):

First off your formatting isnt something anyone wants to spend 15 minutes in fixing.  I have been down that road, it's not fun or amusing.  Second Intel drivers arn't needed.  I have Ubuntu working just as wonderful.  To be honest, a little sincerity goes a far distance when posting questions.  You also posted PC specs from another site, mainly a merchant site.  I am surprised your question hasn't been flagged yet.  It doesn't help your rep score is 145 either.

Comment: with the rep-score does not help you mean that people presume he should know better? (I was a bit puzzled with that part of the remark)